# How to write unit testcase using JEST if text shown conditionally with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

sample.js

```
const Sample = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const onShow = () => {
        setShow(!show);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={onShow}>{show ? 'Hide Text' : 'Show text'}</button>
            {show && <label>Welcome!!</label>}
        </div>
    );
};
export default Sample;
```

Sample.test.js

```
import Sample from '../components/sample';
import React from "react";


test('render Sample text matcher', () => {
    render(<Sample />);
    const titleElement = screen.getByText(/Welcome!!/)
    expect(titleElement).toBeInTheDocument;
})
```

It throw following error. How can I write testcase if element render with state value?

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /Welcome!!/. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

Comment: The initial state of `show` is `false`, so of course the label isn't getting rendered. You need to click the button to toggle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on your button first. Otherwise `show` is false and the text is not displayed.

You can use:

```js
const button = screen.getByRole('button');
fireEvent.click(button); // import this from react-testing-library
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, just after rendering  you could try to do a click on the button that activate your display :

```
document.querySelector('button').click();
```

Comment: How Can I use it using JEST?